# What is wrong with this looping?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, indexing

I can't inderstand what is wrong with this R code, I have several rows and col with a measuament or NA and I basically want to get the min and max value in each line looking amongs the several cols:

```
require(plyr)

census <- read.csv("sps_census.csv")
info <- read.csv("sps_info.csv")


for (i in 1: nrow(census)) {
  trans <- census[i,c("dbh1","dbh2","dbh3","dbh4","dbh5","dbh6","dbh7","dbh8", "dbh9")]
  index.1 <- which (trans != "NA") #some NAs are in the data
  census$min.dbh <- min(trans[1,index.1])
  census$min.dbh.index <- min(index.1)
  census$max.dbh <- max(trans[1,index.1])
  census$max.dbh.index  <- max(index.1)
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to get the answer if you'd tagged your question with the language name you are using.

Comment: which error message do you get?

Comment: I'm thinking that he gets wrong results.

Comment: I am getting an "eternal looping" as I understand.

Comment: You could just use `min(dataitem,na.rm=TRUE)`  and save a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In this line (and the other three similar lines):

```
census$min.dbh <- min(trans[1,index.1])
```

you are assigning an entire column, to all the same value.  Clearly not what you intend.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
census$min.dbh[i] <- min(trans[1,index.1])
```

Note that you can use `apply` to do this sort of thing.  It would be a lot easier for someone to write a working `apply` example, if you supply example data (i.e., make your question a reproducible example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
index <- c"dbh1","dbh2","dbh3","dbh4","dbh5","dbh6","dbh7","dbh8", "dbh9") #or paste("dbh",1:9,sep="")

census$min.dbh <- apply(census[index], 1, min, na.rm=T)
census$min.db.index <- apply(census[index], 1, function(x){ min(which(!is.na(x))) })
census$max.dbh <- apply(census[index], 1, max, na.rm=T)
census$max.db.index <- apply(census[index], 1, function(x){ max(which(!is.na(x))) })
```

Note that I'm using `is.na(x)` instead of `x != "NA"`.

Comment: Package matrixStats has functions `rowMins` and `rowMaxs` (and lots of similar useful functions) which are handy here.